# Odoo 10 : Removing a button from customer form view

Tags: css, xml, forms, button, odoo

I want to remove '**Unpublished on Website**' button from  customer form view.

[image]

This button is not part of form view so when i tried below code ,i got an error that element doesn't exist in parent view:

```
<xpath expr='//div[@class="oe_button_box"]//button[@name="website_publish_button"]' position='replace'>   
   <button type="object" name="callSurvey" icon="contacts_custom/static/description/survey.png" class="oe_stat_button">
        <field string="Surveys"  name="survey_count" widget="statinfo" modifiers="{'readonly': true}"/>
   </button>                   
</xpath>
```

Then i tried to remove it using css. My css.css file :

```
button[name=website_publish_button] 
                {    
                    display:none !important;
                }
```

and template :

```
<openerp>
    <data>
    <!-- Adds all assets in Odoo -->
        <template id="assets_backend" name="contacts_custom assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <!--These links will be called when loading your Odoo -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/contacts_custom/static/css/css.css"/> 

            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

But still button appears.Am i doing something wrong or Is there any other method to remove this button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it extending the view like this:

```
<record id="view_partners_form_website" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.res.partner.form.website</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="website_partner.view_partners_form_website"/>
    <field eval="18" name="priority"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <data>
            <button name="website_publish_button" position="replace">
                <button type="object" name="callSurvey" icon="contacts_custom/static/description/survey.png" class="oe_stat_button">
                    <field string="Surveys" name="survey_count" widget="statinfo" modifiers="{'readonly': true}"/>
                </button>
            </button>
        </data>
    </field>
</record>
```

Add a depends entry to the module `website_partner` to be able to inherit the view that add the button like the snippet above